# Create multidimensional array from 2D array of indices in another multidimensional array in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

Im having a problem I am struggling with.

I have an array with shape (3,4,5) which contains the values across 3 timesteps, for 4 indicators and 5 regions. For the purposes of this example lets say this array is:

`values = np.arange(60).reshape(3,4,5)`

I also have a 'map' which shows the location of the 5 regions on a 5x5 grid. e.g.

```
map = np.array([[1,1,1,2,2],
               [1,1,2,2,2],
               [3,3,3,2,2],
               [3,3,4,4,4],
               [3,3,5,5,4]])
```

What I want is to end up with an array (`result`) which presents the values on a 5x5 grid (similar to `map`), per timestep (3) and indicator (4). so

```
>>>result.shape 
(3,4,5,5)
```

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the 5 in `values.shape` is not related to the `(5, 5)` in `map.shape`, but only to the range of values in `map`. The first thing to do is to make the values in `map` follow the conventional python indexing convention: start counting from zero, not from one.

Here is how to do it with the map having a different shape than the values:

```
import numpy as np

m, n, p = 2, 3, 4
values = np.arange(m*n*p).reshape(m, n, p)

map = np.array([
     [0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3],
     [0, 0, 1, 3, 3, 2],
     [1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2],
     [2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1],
     [2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1]
     ])

q, r = map.shape

map_r = map.reshape(q*r)

# result_r: shape (q*r, m, n)
# If you want to keep the 1-based numbering, index as [:, :, i-1].
result_r = np.array([values[:, :, i] for i in map_r])
result = result_r.transpose(1, 2, 0).reshape(m, n, q, r)

# test
jq, jr = 4, 5
mapval = map[jq, jr]
print(f'map[{jq}, {jr}] = {mapval}')
print(f'result[:, :, {jq}, {jr}] =\n{result[:, :, jq, jr]}')
print(f'values[:, :, {mapval}] =\n{values[:, :, mapval]}')
```

Output:

```
map[4, 5] = 1
result[:, :, 4, 5] =
[[ 1  5  9]
 [13 17 21]]
values[:, :, 1] =
[[ 1  5  9]
 [13 17 21]]
```

As an aside: multidimensional arrays often work more cleanly if you define the left-most index to represent a higher level concept. If you can phrase it as "a list of N lists of M widgets", the natural array shape would be `(N, M)`, not `(M,N)`.  So, you would have `values.shape = (p, m, n)` and `result.shape (q,r,m,n)` (and maybe swap `m` and `n` as well, depending on how you will process the data later on). You would avoid a lot of `[:, :]` indices and `transpose` operations.

Comment: Thanks, that works like a charm! Gonna spend some time playing around with this method as it will be very useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation using np.pad:

```
values = np.arange(60).reshape(3,4,5)

# I renamed map to mapping, because map is a basic function in python

mapping = np.array([[1,1,1,2,2],
                  [1,1,2,2,2],
                  [3,3,3,2,2],
                  [3,3,4,4,4],
                  [3,3,5,5,4]])

v0,v1,v2 = values.shape
m0,m1 = mapping.shape

new = np.zeros((v0,v1,m0,m1))

for a in range(v2):
    q = values[:,:,a].reshape(v0,v1,1)
    r,c = np.where((mapping-1)==a)
    npad = ((0,0), (0,0), (0,len(c)-1))
    new[:,:,r,c] = np.pad(q, pad_width=npad, mode='symmetric')
```

Comment: The `np.where` is a slow operation if you do this repeatedly (inside a loop) on a large dataset.